# I am trying to input data in mongoDB from a form. but the data being input is different from what i am submitting in the form

Tags: mongodb, flask

I have created a form to input shop name, shop address and gst no. When i am submitting the form the data in mongoDB is some random details i have used to input a long time ago. same details are being entered as i submit the form[here is the what is being entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQkTc.png)

here is the code i have used to submit the form

```
---
`from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)


client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client['shop_database']
collection = db['shops']

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('register.html')

@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        shop_name = request.form['shopName']
        shop_address = request.form['shopAddress']
        gst_number = request.form['gstNumber']
        
     
        shop_data = {
            'shop_name': shop_name,
            'shop_address': shop_address,
            'gst_number': gst_number
        }
        collection.insert_one(shop_data)
        
        return 'Data submitted successfully!'
    else:
        return 'Error in form submission'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)`
```

here is the html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Shop Registration Form</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4>Shop Registration</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form method="POST" action="/submit">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="shopName" class="form-label">Shop Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shopName" name="shopName" required>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="shopAddress" class="form-label">Shop Address</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="shopAddress" name="shopAddress" rows="3" required></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="gstNumber" class="form-label">GST Registration No.</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gstNumber" name="gstNumber" required>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). **1.** You've pasted an image of 3 entries when viewed in Mongo Compass. Use the "Copy to Clipboard" feature of Mongo Compass and paste that as **formatted code**. **2.** What was your form input data? That's nowhere in your question so there's no reason for us to assume that the DB version is incorrect. **3.** Add a print/log for `request.form` so you and we can see what was provided in the form vs what was saved. What is _"random details"_?

Comment: **4.** You may also need to show the rendered form HTML or the template to ensure that the form fields and what you're looking up is correct. Without any logs or prints of the form data before you insert it into Mongo, it's unclear what is right/wrong or input/saved.

Comment: @aneroid thanks i will keep it in mind not to upload images next time.
i added the print statement as suggested
Form Data Received:
Shop Name: abcd
Shop Address: ghgfcfbx
GST Number: 5465656
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2024 16:12:38] "POST /submit?shopName=aaa&shopAddress=bbb&gstNumber=111 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78213280/edit) and add the output of the print statement there; rather than the comments. It's information/clarity directly about the question. You also need to add the ```text``` of the record/document which was saved to the DB, _not the image_ of the record.